# A family of posets

Tags: posets

Consider the family of all (finite) posets that can be obtained by repeatedly applying one of the following three operations (starting e.g. with the empty poset):

(O1) Disjoint union of one or more posets that have been obtained previously

(O2) Adding a new greatest element

(O3) Adding a new least element

Is this a well-known concept, and in particular, is there a specific name for such a poset? Note that if we only allow (O1) and (O2) (or only (O1) and (O3)), we get precisely posets whose Hasse diagrams are (unions of) rooted trees.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This family is very close to the notion of "skeletal poset" in http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6178.

Comment: sounds different: the 4-element poset $b>a<c<d$ has the above property but is not skeletal according to Ex 9.6 in your link

Comment: Right, sorry, it is significantly different: skeletal posets only allow taking disjoint unions of posets of the same rank. Meanwhile, I think they are also not a subset of the class here because you are allowed to add multiple greatest or least elements at the same time as well.

Comment: This is contained in the set of series-parallel posets. Have you tried to count them and look at oeis.org ?

Comment: Yes, the sequence starts (unless I have made a mistake) 1, 2, 5, 14, 40, 121, 373, 1184,..., which is not in the OEIS.

Comment: @StephanWagner Great question! Do you know a finite poset that cannot be generated using (O1)-(O3)? I have a candidate: consider $\{0,1\}\times \{0,1\}$ and set $(a,b) < (x,y)$ iff $a = 0 \land x = 1$.

Comment: Yes, the poset you mention is such an example, and the N-poset (four elements $a,b,c,d$ with relations $a < b$, $b > c$, $c < d$ and no others) is the only other one with four elements or less. In fact, posets generated by (O1)-(O3) seem to be precisely those that do not contain either of the two as an induced subposet, if I am not much mistaken. N-free posets are precisely the series-parallel posets mentioned by F.C., I could not find anything special about forbidding the other type.

Comment: Now in the encyclopedia as https://oeis.org/A301871